# Divide 2 PySpark DataFrames Based on Column Names

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 DataFrames with hundreds of columns. `Df1` looks like this:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | ..... 
1     .2     .3     .3
2     .1     .4     .2
....
```

`Df2` looks like this, and only has 1 row of values:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | ..... 
.2     .3     .3
```

I'd like to divide each row of `Df1` by `Df2`, so I should end up with something like this:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | ..... 
1   .2/.2  .3/.3  .3/.3
2   .1/.2  .4/.3  .2/.3
```

How can I do this without specifically specifying column names during a join, given I have hundreds of columns? Thanks in advance!

Comment: udf could be an approach. What is the file size (If it is around 10 to 15 GB) may be you can also use pandas chunksize and do your calculation and write back the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got value of df2 and zipped it with df1. Then iterated through zipped structure, and got division value. Hope this helps. Here is the code snippet and output I got.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df1 = spark.createDataFrame( [('A',2,4),('B',6,8), ('C',10,12) ],['col1','col2','col3'] )
df2 = spark.createDataFrame( [(2,2)],['div1','div2'] )
df1.show()
df2.show()

lr = df2.rdd.take(1)
for c, v in zip(df1.columns[1:], lr[0]):
    df1 = df1.withColumn(c, col(c)/v)
df1.show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   2|   4|
|   B|   6|   8|
|   C|  10|  12|
+----+----+----+

+----+----+
|div1|div2|
+----+----+
|   2|   2|
+----+----+

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A| 1.0| 2.0|
|   B| 3.0| 4.0|
|   C| 5.0| 6.0|
+----+----+----+
```